# Updating just Safari through terminal on Big Sur

Tags: macos, terminal, safari, bash, script

There is a new version of Safari and I'm trying to update just Safari on my machine using a terminal command. I have Big Sur 11.6.3. I've done `Softwareupdate -l` and I see the Safari update there. I try `softwareupdate -i --product-types Safari` but it never works. I'm trying to avoid using the `Label` name.

On my Monterey device, I know `softwareupdate -i -safari-only` works. However, I can't find a good way to just update Safari on Big Sur devices using a terminal command.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

We have to list updates and apply the exact specific label for this to work.

Use `softwareupdate -l -a` to list the available updates and their labels.

Use `softwareupdate -l -a | grep -i Safari` to list the available Safari updates and their labels.

Use `softwareupdate -i Safari15.3BigSurAuto-15.3` to install the latest Safari update. Use the corresponding label if you want another version.

`softwareupdate` will try to quit Safari before installing it.
You’ll also perhaps need to reboot user space if you can’t guarantee the person using the Mac doesn’t have Safari running or any of its libraries.

Answer (score 8):

Okay, after the help of bmike I came up with this. This will look for a Safari update, grab the label and use the label to update Safari. That way the script will work with any future Safari update with a different label name.

```
check=$(softwareupdate -l | grep Safari | grep -o 'Safari[^[:blank:]]*' | head -n 1)
 echo "$check"
softwareupdate -i "$check"
```

Comment: Nice solve! It’s ok to post your own answer in addition to my answer…